# Anyone knows from where to get that jQuery tags editor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Someday i've downloaded a very nice jquery editor but i lost it and i only have a screenshot of it. You just type a tag and press return or space and it's will be inside a nice box, and you can delete it by only pressing the backspace key or the close icon.

[image: jQuery Tags Editor]

Please don't suggest me [That](http://blog.crazybeavers.se/wp-content/demos/jquery.tag.editor/) because it's so poor and the tags are inserted outside the input box.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How's [this one](http://levycarneiro.com/projects/tag-it/example.html)?

Comment: You're the best, it's not exactly the one i had, but it's perfect, more padding and it's will be the same :)